# How to enforce naming convention during repository creation in subversion

Tags: svn

When we create a repository using the svnadmin create  command, is it possible for us to enforce naming convention on the value of **reponame**. For example I want all the repository names to have information like the division for which the project is created. ie. All repository names should follow the convention.
**'division_name'_'project_name'**_repo

Comment: Do you mean naming of repositories?  Or the naming of files added to a repository?  Please give an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @therefromhere  I have updated my question and added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since creating a repository is something you can only do with the `svnadmin` command, it isn't something you can put hooks on.

Generally, anybody that has access to `svnadmin` on your SVN server, should be trusted not to make a mess of things, since they can do a lot more harm than simply create a repository with a bad name!

I would suggest having a checklist or something for creating a repository (maybe including a wrapper script for `svnadmin create` with checks on the name), if it is a common action which you want to make sure gets done correctly.

Comment: +1 if you can't trust the admin you've got bigger problems than naming conventions!

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, a repository is nothing else than a directory. Additionally, unless there's a way to obtain division names programmatically, I can't figure out how Subversion could possibly know whether a given name is valid or not.

The obvious solution is organise your repositories in such a way that they can't be created directly (e.g., remove access permissions for the directory that contains them) and provide a specific tool as the only way to create new repos (e.g., a simple web front-end) through a form that asks for the specific details. You could even show divisions in a drop down list! Of course, this implies that direct file access is disabled and all client-side operations are made via HTTP or SVN protocols.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I gave the name of division as an example. We are also thinking about creating a tool for creating repositories etc. But I was checking whether there is any easy alternative provided in subversion by default.